# Using VIM for C++/Qt development w/ Autocomplete

Tags: c++, qt, vim, autocomplete

At work, I mainly program in C++ and when it needs to be graphical/multi-threaded/network enabled use Qt. Our environment is windows and I currently program w/ a combination of Visual Studio(debuggin purposes only) and Qt-Creator for actual coding (like their autocomplete better than VS).

At home, I mainly use linux (fedora) and still use Qt-Creator as I haven't found an alternative. I use VIM for pretty much everything else (editor wise) and basically LOVE everything about it.

I want to be able to use VIM for my programming (both at home AND work) but find that I'm not as productive without autocomplete.

Anyone have a good tutorial, forum post, or personal experience on how to get 'good' autocomplete (yes... not exactly very descriptive... 'good'...) for C++ and Qt in VIM? I believe it is very for linux/vim/qt/c++ but is it also possible for windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1608 
A pain to configure, but after all you'll get VS-like autocompletion + all the tasty omnicompletion stuff like `Ctrl-P` to complete the word, `Ctrl-X-Ctrl-L` to complete the line etc.

Comment: thanks for the link. Looks to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: works really well.  Thank you for posting.  One note, on the link, be sure to read the comment near the bottom.  Having it autocomplete local variables names, too is useful.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think I have any magic settings in my vimrc which enables this, but I can just start typing and then (while still being in insert mode) press `Ctrl+N` to have vim suggest completions. It seems to check the open buffers for possible completions. It's not perfect, but in 98% of the cases it does what I want and there's no setup work needed.

Comment: very interesting, I will have to try this out!

Comment: Glad i used the search instead of posting another question about this. This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: This has really turned out to be a time saver, so long as you keep a bunch of files open in different buffers.

Comment: See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-N and 
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Any_word_completion for more info!

Comment: I wanted to return to this answer to give an update... I now use native VIM (combined with tmux) solely for my c++ development. The trick is to use this default autocomplete WITH as many open buffers as you need. I load VIM at cmd line (using find and grep) with every directory and file I need. I then use `Ctrl+N` or `Ctrl+P` combined with `:b filename` (which has its own search). It gives you items from your currently opened buffer, then other switched windows, then other open tabs, then recently opened buffers, then anything else might match... https://gitlab.com/snippets/1885618

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [OmniCpp](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520).

It's a set of Vim-scripts that enables auto-completion based on c-tags.

It is not exactly straightforward to set up but works pretty well afterwards. Basically you have to generate the c-tags for the include files you use. Then the plugin integrates into Vim to complete what you type, depending on the variables type.

Comment: any links that would help me get started? Looks like I will need ctags and omnicpp. Available on windows?

Comment: @g19fanatic: Absolutely. I use it on Linux and Windows. Works like a charm. Take a look at the link I posted and this one: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Since it is "A pain to configure" vim for omnicompletion
and no one mentioned it and since you want a solution on your windows pc at work too, the best and most painless option I found - and am sure will
help a lot others - is activating "Fake Vim" in the qt creator
since it is preinstalled in the options in recent versions.

`Tools-->Options-->FakeVim and [x] Use Fake Vim`

[Use Fake Vim in the qt creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLr51.png)

That way the QT-creator behaves like vim and it shouldn't
make a difference to open qt-crator  instead of vim .